# How to identify sequences in R

Tags: r, sequence

This question is an extension of [R - identify consecutive sequences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31439273/r-identify-consecutive-sequences)

I have a data frame in which I need to keep only those trials where in the column ROI I have a consecutive sequence of *_aCORRECT1* and *_CORRECT1*. It doesn't matter how many times *_aCORRECT1* and *_CORRECT1* occur, they can be repeated.

In the example below, I can keep ntrial 78 and 201, because *_aCORRECT1* is followed by *_CORRECT1*.
However, I need to remove the ntrial 10 and 400. In the trial 10 *_aCORRECT1* is not followed by *_CORRECT1*. In the trial 400 *_CORRECT1* is not preceded by *_aCORRECT1*.

Many thanks!

```
subject ROI                 ntrial 
sbj05   ff                  78     
sbj05   as                  78     
sbj05   fgfsd               78     
sbj05   sgf                 78     
sbj05   jh                  78     
sbj05   sgsgsfg             78     
sbj05   fgsfg               78     
sbj05   sgf_aCORRECT1       78     
sbj05   dfs_CORRECT1        78     
sbj05   ffg                 78     
sbj05   sdfdsf              78     
sbj05   sl                  78     
sbj05   wgrt                78     
sbj05   qswefrd             201    
sbj05   ssdg                201    
sbj05   sdgfdsg             201    
sbj05   sgsgd               201    
sbj05   sgsdg               201    
sbj05   dd_aCORRECT1        201    
sbj05   dd_aCORRECT1        201    
sbj05   ffds_CORRECT1       201    
sbj05   ffds_CORRECT1       201    
sbj05   ffds_CORRECT1       201    
sbj05   hy                  201    
sbj05   gfg                 201    
sbj05   nbc                 201    
sbj05   cvbvn               10     
sbj05   kpj                 10     
sbj05   nbvnb               10     
sbj05   mnm                 10     
sbj05   dghsfh_aCORRECT1    10     
sbj05   gdh                 10   
sbj05   fgjj                10     
sbj05   gnjdg               10     
sbj05   gf                  10     
sbj05   qw                  400    
sbj05   vfs                 400    
sbj05   zx                  400    
sbj05   zvzv                400    
sbj05   zvzv_CORRECT1       400    
sbj05   zvzd_CORRECT1       400    
sbj05   zvv                 400    
sbj05   cv                  400    
sbj05   v                   400    
sbj05   mngy                400
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`, `df1` is a dataframe telling you which values of ntrial should be kept.  This is done by setting logical indicators for aCORRECT and _CORRECT and checking whether adjacent values exist for each grouped ntrial. `df2` is then the version of `df` containing only the valid ntrials

```
df1 <- df %>% mutate(aCOR=grepl("aCORRECT",ROI),COR=grepl("_CORRECT",ROI)) %>%
              group_by(ntrial) %>% summarise(keep=any(aCOR & lead(COR)))

df2 <- df[df$ntrial %in% df1$ntrial[df1$keep],]


df1
# A tibble: 4 × 2
  ntrial  keep
   <int> <lgl>
1     10 FALSE
2     78  TRUE
3    201  TRUE
4    400 FALSE

df2
   subject           ROI ntrial
1    sbj05            ff     78
2    sbj05            as     78
3    sbj05         fgfsd     78
4    sbj05           sgf     78
5    sbj05            jh     78
6    sbj05       sgsgsfg     78
7    sbj05         fgsfg     78
8    sbj05 sgf_aCORRECT1     78
9    sbj05  dfs_CORRECT1     78
10   sbj05           ffg     78
11   sbj05        sdfdsf     78
12   sbj05            sl     78
13   sbj05          wgrt     78
14   sbj05       qswefrd    201
15   sbj05          ssdg    201
16   sbj05       sdgfdsg    201
17   sbj05         sgsgd    201
...
```

Comment: for some reason this code doesn't detect when for example *_CORRECT* is not preceded by *_aCORRECT*. Any idea why?

Comment: It works on the data you supplied.  For `ntrial=400` it correctly detects that `_CORRECT` is not preceded by `_aCORRECT` and concludes that this value of `ntrial` should be excluded (i.e. `keep=FALSE` in `df1`).  Is that not the behaviour you are looking for?  Or do you have other data that it doesn't work on?

Comment: I have data with more subjects and it doesn't work - not sure why. I also tried to `group_by(subject,ntrial)` but it doesn't help.

Comment: Can you give an example of some data that it doesn't work on?

Answer (score 0):

We can extract the relevant portions of the two target strings in `ROI` and then filter to select only those values of `ntrial` where the two target strings occur consecutively.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% group_by(subject, ntrial) %>%
  filter(grepl("_aCORR_CORR", paste(str_extract(ROI, "_a?CORR"), collapse="")))
```

> ```
>    subject           ROI ntrial
> 1    sbj05            ff     78
> 2    sbj05            as     78
> 3    sbj05         fgfsd     78
> 4    sbj05           sgf     78
> 5    sbj05            jh     78
> 6    sbj05       sgsgsfg     78
> 7    sbj05         fgsfg     78
> 8    sbj05 sgf_aCORRECT1     78
> 9    sbj05  dfs_CORRECT1     78
> 10   sbj05           ffg     78
> 11   sbj05        sdfdsf     78
> 12   sbj05            sl     78
> 13   sbj05          wgrt     78
> 14   sbj05       qswefrd    201
> 15   sbj05          ssdg    201
> 16   sbj05       sdgfdsg    201
> 17   sbj05         sgsgd    201
> 18   sbj05         sgsdg    201
> 19   sbj05  dd_aCORRECT1    201
> 20   sbj05  dd_aCORRECT1    201
> 21   sbj05 ffds_CORRECT1    201
> 22   sbj05 ffds_CORRECT1    201
> 23   sbj05 ffds_CORRECT1    201
> 24   sbj05            hy    201
> 25   sbj05           gfg    201
> 26   sbj05           nbc    201
> ```

Here's a `data.table` version that also uses base R `gsub` instead of `str_extract`:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, .SD[grepl("_aCORR_CORR", paste(gsub(".*(_a?CORR).*","\\1", ROI),collapse=""))], by=.(subject,ntrial)]
```